# MSSQL module of metricbeat 7.6.2 does not start and has no error in logs

Tags: elastic-stack, metricbeat

I have followed the instructions provided in the documentation. After enabling the MSSQL module of metricbeat and modifying the mssql.yml with the below configuration for MSSQL metricbeat, the service does not start. There is no error in the log. The SQL credentials are SQL server login and not windows authentication. The metric beat does not start with this configuration.

## Module: mssql

## Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/7.6/metricbeat-module-mssql.html

```
metricbeat.modules:
- module: mssql
  metricsets:
    - "transaction_log"
    - "performance"
  hosts: ["sqlserver://servername\user_name"]
  username: ab.efqmpznfou
  password: Q@$$x0se
  period: 10s
```

Below are environment details:

```
OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778] 
Metric beat: metricbeat-7.6.2-windows-x86_64
```

I have also tried with below config

```
metricbeat.modules:
- module: mssql
  metricsets:
    - "transaction_log"
    - "performance"
  hosts: ["sqlserver://ab.efqmpznfou:Q@$$x0se@servername\user_name"]
  period: 10s
```

Answer (score 1):

If your password has the '@' special character then the module will fail. Please change the password and don't include any special characters in it such as '@', '/', ''